# Could you trick a user of a Death Note into misspelling the names of the Kira task force four times?

Tags: death-note

If you have access to a Death Note, know the rule that four unintentional misspellings result in immunity to the Death Note, and are hunting someone with a Death Note, couldn't you trick someone you gave the Death Note to misspell the names of everyone in your task force four times?

I know nobody got a chance to do this in the anime, and probably not the manga either, but this still seems the obvious method of setting up a Kira task force: make the members immune to the Death Note without telling anyone, putting Kira in the dark in a way that gives you a significant advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could, and having people be mistaken about the names and faces of investigators was one of L's main strategies.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Rule XXXV explicitly says "the owner" and after Light still was the owner, they could not just hand it to anyone. Rule IX however does not specify that fact. Maybe IX was simplified and it has to be the owner, maybe XXXV is wrong.

The next problem is that the person has to really try to write the names. Who knows what happens if one is to copy a name four times and has the wrong spelling. Maybe the tricked one die, maybe the tricker.

Comment: So as long as rule IX applies and not XXXV, L could have handed the DN to a criminal who is on death row and told him "This is my name. Write it with a misspelling in the first name so that we see if you cheat. Try to kill me and we shoot you, write my name with a misspelling four times and you will die on a heard attack but I promis your family will be cared of." The outcome of the trick is quite unclear but this way will work. :D:D:D Except af far as I remember L does not know his name himself

Answer (score 0):

In the anime, the task force did not know about this rule. They only knew what was written on the notebook's inside cover. The additional information that Light pried out of Ryuk or discovered through experimentation are known only to him, not the taskforce. He would not reveal to them the things he learned, for obvious reasons (he doesn't actually want to make them immune to the Death Note, and also doesn't want to make himself look suspicious). Since the taskforce members didn't use the Death Note to kill people, they would not have discovered this rule. L, who was the only one willing to experiment with the Death Note, died before he got the chance. (I don't remember if this was true for the manga, so not speaking for that.)

Also, keep in mind that the rule you are referring to (rule XXXV) gives a person definite immunity to the particular Death Note where their name was misspelled. They might still be vulnerable to all other Death Notes out there, it's really not that clear.